# jquery scrolling help

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible without the help of a plugin to make a page scroll to a certain position on the click of a button?

Basically, if the user clicks a button a popup gets displayed in the center of the screen, if the user uses the button at the bottom of the page, the popup is sometimes out of view so I am wanting to couple the showing of the popup and scolling to the top of the popup on the clickup.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you show the popup with CSS `position: fixed` and center it on the screen? Anything can be done without a plugin. It's just JavaScript ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the CSS

```
position : fixed
```

is the best bet for your problem.

In case if you would like to know the way to scroll the page to certain position using jQuery then here it is.

Use [jQuery's scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) function in the following way.

```
jQuery(window).scrollTop(<position>);
```

Using jQuery to handle scrolling will also resolve any browser incompatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can get that effect with the [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView) method. But it's probably better to centre your popup on the window rather than the document to avoid the problem in the first place ...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes lean and mean works nicely. No Plugins, No JQuery:
[window.scrollTo()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp)

Watch out for cross browser incompatibilities that might creep in. That's the point of JQuery ;)